# Calculating fraction of line segment point is on using ST_LineLocatePoint

Tags: postgis

I have a points table and would like to calculate the fraction of the line the nearest point is on:

```
SELECT
    ST_LineLocatePoint(
        ST_LineMerge(public.streams.geom),
    control_pts.cp_locations.geom) 
FROM
    public.streams;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cp_locations" LINE 95:
> ...ineLocatePoint(ST_LineMerge(public.streams.geom), control_pt...

Comment: FROM must contain all the tables that you use on the left side. I don't know how you have named the schemas and tables but maybe it would work as `from public.streams, control_pts.cp_locations`.

Comment: What you are facing here is one of the most fundamental concept of relational databases - joining relations. I know this is likely not what you want to hear, but I strongly suggest to get familiar with the core syntax of the SQL dialect before attempting to add complexity to your expressions: do yourself a favor and go through a handful of tutorials and examples, while looking up the respective syntax in the PostgreSQL docs. PostGIS and its functionality is build on top of those core language and database concepts, and without a basic understanding you *will* eventually smash your keyboard...

Comment: You're missing a `JOIN` and probably a `WHERE`

Comment: Thank you @geozelot, I am beginning to see more and more use of postgis for my work and need to learn the fundamentals before diving into great complexity, solid advice.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the PostGIS linear referencing workshop chapter I utilized the following code by the author

[link to chapter]([http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/linear_referencing.html#:~:text=Linear%20referencing%20(sometimes%20called%20%E2%80%9Cdynamic,miles%20along%20a%20highway%20network)](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/linear_referencing.html#:%7E:text=Linear%20referencing%20(sometimes%20called%20%E2%80%9Cdynamic,miles%20along%20a%20highway%20network))

```
-- Move pts to stream and calculate
-- fraction of stream CP is located on
CREATE TABLE control_pts.fractional_measure AS
-- We first need to get a candidate set of maybe-closest
-- stream, ordered by id and distance...
WITH ordered_nearest AS (
SELECT
  ST_GeometryN(streams.geom,1) AS streams_geom,
  streams.id AS streams_id,
  pts.geom AS pts_geom,
  pts.cp_no AS pts_id,
  ST_Distance(streams.geom::geography, pts.geom::geography) AS distance_to_stream
FROM public.streams streams
  JOIN control_pts.cp_locations pts
  ON ST_DWithin(streams.geom::geography, pts.geom::geography, 2000)
ORDER BY pts_id, distance_to_stream ASC
)
-- use the 'distinct on' PostgreSQL feature to get the first
-- stream (the nearest) for each unique stream id. We can then
-- pass that one stream into ST_LineLocatePoint along with
-- its candidate pt to calculate the measure.
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (pts_id)
  pts_id,
  streams_id,
  ST_LineLocatePoint(streams_geom, pts_geom) AS fraction,
  distance_to_stream
FROM ordered_nearest;

-- Primary keys are useful for visualization software
ALTER TABLE control_pts.fractional_measure ADD PRIMARY KEY (pts_id);

CREATE table control_pts.controlpoints AS
SELECT
  frac_events.pts_id,frac_events.fraction,
  ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_GeometryN(streams.geom, 1), frac_events.fraction) AS geom,
  frac_events.streams_id
FROM control_pts.fractional_measure frac_events
JOIN public.streams streams
ON (streams.id = frac_events.streams_id);
```